# How to using selenium.addCustomRequestHeader

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I want to add headers into my HTTP request for a particular test case Selenium to authenticate. I using form selenium.addCustomRequestHeader(key, value) but no have expected result. In my console have warning message:"WARNING: getString(addCustomRequestHeader) saw a bad result OK". 
Code:

```
    @Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
    seleniumServer.start();
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore",
            TARGET_URL);
    selenium.start("addCustomRequestHeader=true");

    @Test
public void testValidCookieSessionIDGamen() throws Exception {
            selenium.addCustomRequestHeader(key,value);
            selenium.open(TARGET_URL);
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("a"));
}
```

Any idea of how can I do this? Thanks for your time